# How to set many to many field optional in django admin form

Tags: django, many-to-many

I want to make optional m2m field and implement setting values in django admin form using horizontal filter. In order to make it optional, I added some optional parameters in ManyToManyField class constructor. I set null param and blank param like the following.

```
night = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe, related_name = "night", null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Night Snack')
```

But in add page, There's no horizontal filter like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTc0R.png) for setting night field values because it's optional.

I want it to appear even when it's optional, so I can add some recipes or nothing into it.
Could anyone solve this problem?

Comment: When you write in field `null=True` & `blank=True` it means field are optional. Did you hit makemigration & migrate command!

Comment: I solved the problem. I forgot to set the field in fields variable of model admin class, anyway, thanks.